# Problema con combobox e items duplicados

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un `combobox` que lo relleno con datos desde **mysql**, el problema que tengo actualmente, es que el `combobox` me duplica los valores, ejemplo,si le agrego 5 items, me mostrara los 5 y otros 5 que son copias de los primeros, les dejo el código y una foto de ejemplo:

```
public void docenteAlumno(String seccion,JComboBox cb,JComboBox cb2,DocenteMenu estado){
         ArrayList <String> usuarios= new ArrayList();
         Connection con= new AbrirBasedeDatos().conectar();
         int yy=cb.getItemCount();
         String xx=String.valueOf(yy);
         if(xx!=null && !xx.isEmpty()){
            cb.removeAll();
         }
         usuarios.clear();
         cb.addItem("Seleccione Alumno");


          try {
           if(con!=null){
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             String query ="select * from inasistencia where seccion = '"+seccion+"'and leida=false and justificado='si'";

             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

             while(rs.next()){
                 usuarios.add(rs.getString("user"));


             }
             removeDuplicates(usuarios);



             for(int i=0;i<usuarios.size();i++){
                 String query2="select * from usuario where user='"+usuarios.get(i)+"'";

                 ResultSet rss=st.executeQuery(query2);
                 while(rss.next()){

                     cb.addItem(rss.getString("nombre"));
                 }
             }
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
           }else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(estado,"Asegurate de estar conectado a internet");
           }
          }catch (SQLException sqle){
              System.out.println("el error fue: "+sqle.getMessage());
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(estado,"Ocurrio un error, vuelve a intentarlo más tarde");
          }
       new AbrirBasedeDatos().cerrarConexion();





    }

    private void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list){
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (index < list.size() - 1) {
        String item = list.get(index);
       List<String> tail = list.subList(index + 1, list.size());
        while (tail.equals(item)) {
            tail.remove(item);
            count++;
        }
        index++;
    }

       }
```

asi es como se ve actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: ¿Utilizas el método `removeDuplicates(usuarios);` para remover los duplicados? De ser así, tu problema podría ser generado en el while y evidentemente ahí es donde se agregan los usuarios. Eso quiere decir que el problema se genera al momento de comprobar `rs.next()` y por lo tanto, quiere decir que en tu mysql se está leyendo dos veces... ¿por casualidad la tabla inasistencia genera dos columnas?

Comment: Aparece dos veces seleccione alumno, con lo cual suena a que estas llamando 2 veces a la funcion docenteAlumno

Comment: @C.Rodriguez utilizo el metodo removeduplicados, para remover a los usuarios duplicados del arraylist, y asi buscarlos 1 vez en la segunda consulta

Comment: @gbianchi exacto, el metodo que carga el arraylist es el evento del combobox seccion itemstated change, lo que al seleccionar algo en el primer combobox, lo auto ejecuta, por eso, borro los datos del arraylist y del combobox al iniciar el metodo, para que no se dupliquen

Comment: ponle un debug con un contador.. a ver si no pasas dos veces por ahi.. te apuesto a que es eso..

Comment: @gbianchi, si pasa 2 veces, pero no como te explique anteriormente, no puedo evitar que pase la primera vez por autorun, ya que el evento, solo lo ejecuta, ademas el metodo comboBox.removeAllItems(), me genera un puntero nulo

Comment: no entiendo. sabes porque pasa 2 veces? lo que tenes que evitar es eso...

Comment: @gbianchi, el combobox se carga en el evento del combobox de arriba, segun el valor que tenga, cuando uno da click al primer combox, el metodo se ejecuta solo, entonces cuando yo ya salecciono un valor, es la segunda vez que ejecuta, por ende no puedo impedir el primero

Comment: Según leí acá https://stackoverflow.com/a/330607/8954823 al utilizar el ItemStateChanged es normal que al deseleccionar un item y seleccionar otro, el "state" (estado seleccionado o deseleccionado) cambiará para ambas opciones, es decir... se llamará dos veces

Comment: También dice que recomienda usar un ActionListener en vez de ese. Además un comentario menciona que aún llamando removeAll() se ejecutará dos veces

Comment: esa es la respuesta @C.Rodriguez.. queres traducirla?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/330602/8954823 ahí está la buena respuesta, es una buena manera determinar si el item está seleccionado o deseleccionado utilizando `e.getStateChange()`

Comment: Sí, claro @gbianchi, parafraseando comenta: "El ItemStateChanged comienza a funcionar incorrectamente cuando dejas un item y colocas otro. No utilices un ItemStateChanged, en vez de este, utiliza un ActionListener el cuál es bueno para manipular eventos de un ComboBox. Puedes utilizar el ItemStateListener si por aparte necesitas comprobar cuando el item está seleccionado y luego deja de estarlo, y al cambiar el estado del item, esto provoca una rellamada a itemStateChanged

Comment: no @C.Rodriguez, escribelo como respuesta ;) ganate tus puntos diarios :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A petición de @gbianchi, al parecer el problema es generado por el mismo **itemStateChanged**, ya que este evento es llamado dos veces de forma normal.

La primera vez cuando el item seleccionado deja de estarlo (es decir,
su estado cambia a *deseleccionado*) y la segunda vez cuando el nuevo
item es seleccionado (pasa de estar *deseleccionado* a
*seleccionado*).

Como mencioné en el comentario:

> El ItemStateChanged comienza a funcionar
> incorrectamente
> cuando dejas un item y colocas otro.
>
> No utilices un ItemStateChanged,
> en vez de este, utiliza un ActionListener el cuál es bueno para
> manipular eventos de un ComboBox.
>
> Puedes utilizar el ItemStateListener
> si por aparte necesitas comprobar cuando el item está seleccionado y
> luego deja de estarlo.
>
> Al cambiar el estado del item, esto provoca
> una rellamada a itemStateChanged

Entonces, es mejor utilizar el **ActionPerformed** del **ActionListener** del **JComboBox**.

Si por fuerza debes utilizar el **ItemStateChanged** entonces, comprueba con un **if** si el estado del item es "seleccionado", así obtienes el item y no pasará dos veces, el estado del item lo obtienes con `e.getStateChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago de esta forma primero lo creo un metodo de tipo resultset en la capa de acceso a datos.

Es ahi donde ejecuto la sentencia `sql`

```
select distic nombre from grupo
```

Y luego en el formulario de la vista creo un metodo para cargar los datos i lo inicio en el metodo constructor de la clase.

```
//metodo contructor


public IfrmSalidaEG() {
    initComponents();
    cargarGrupo();

}

//este el metodo para cargar en el combo

 private void cargarGrupo(){
      ResultSet rs;    
         try{ 
              rs=fun.cargarGrupo();

            while(rs.next()){
                rs.getString("Gru_Sal_Id");
                        cboGrupo.addItem(rs.getString("Gru_Sal_Id"));   

            }
         }catch(Exception e){

         }
     }
```